# close fancybox after confirm form in ajax success

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, fancybox

I have problem with close my fancybox after submit registration form in my web.
I using cms pro system....

With this I showing fancybox include form:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    var str = $("#subscriber_application").serialize(); 
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "ajax/user.php",
          data: str,
         success: function (msg){
                $("div#subscriber_response").html(msg);
                $("#subscriber_application").hide();
            }
          });
}
```

My html:

```
<div id="divForm" style="display:none;min-height: 400px;">
<div class="fr" style="min-height: 400px;">        
        <div>
          <div style="position:relative">
               <div id="msgholder"></div>
          </div>
        <form action="" method="post" id="admin_form" name="admin_form">
          <input name="email" type="text" size="45" maxlength="40" class="home_input"   placeholder="Email Address" />
          <input name="token" type="text" size="45" maxlength="40" class="home_input"   placeholder="Token" />
          <input name="submit" value="&nbsp;" type="submit" class="account_activate"/>
        </form>
      <?php echo $core->doForm("accActivate","ajax/user.php");?>
      </div>


<div style="width:800px;"></div>

<h1>Subscribe For Free Application</h1>
<hr />
<p>&nbsp</p>
<div class="registracia">
  <div id="subscriber_response" class="msgErrors"></div>
  <div id="post_your_requirement_success" ></div>
  <form action=""  method="post" id="subscriber_application" name="subscriber_application" style="width:270px;">
    <p>
      <input data-progression="" type="text" data-helper="Username should be at least 3 characters long" name="username" value="" class="home_input" placeholder="User name" name="username" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input data-progression="" type="text" data-helper="Add your E-mail" name="email" class="home_input"   placeholder="Email address" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['subscriber_application']['email_address'])):echo $_SESSION['subscriber_application']['email_address'];endif; ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input data-progression="" type="text" data-helper="Your Restaurant Name" name="hotel_name" class="home_input"   placeholder="Restaurant name" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input data-progression="" type="password" data-helper="Add Password - min 4 characters" name="password" class="home_input" placeholder="Password" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <!---  <input tabindex="13" type="checkbox" id="flat-checkbox-1"  />I agree, I've read <a href="#">terms of use</a> -->
    </p>
      <input name="submit" type="submit"  id="submit" value="&nbsp;" class="sign_in" />
      <input name="doapplication" type="hidden" value="1" />    
    </form>
</div>
<div style="social">
<h2>Sign in with social network!</h2>
<ul>
    <li style="list-style:none"><img src="../demo/theme/master/images/g+.jpg" /></li>
    <li style="list-style:none"><img src="../demo/theme/master/images/faceb.jpg" /></li> 
</ul>
</div>
```

my button :

```
<a href="#divForm" id="btnForm">
      <button type="button" class="way-start" style="border-radius: 5px;height: 60px;width: 180px;background-color: green;border: 1px solid green;font-size: 26px;font-weight: 300;font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Sans Serif;">Get the app!</button>
</a>
```

I will be grateful for every opinion !!!
Thanks!!!

Comment: could you show the html for `#btnForm`? I think you don't really need to apply css styles within `onStart` and `onClosed`. On the other hand, if you close fancybox after form submission, you won't be able to see the "thank you" message unless you set a delay (setTimeout) or add a button to manually close fancybox: what would you like to do?

Comment: Hello JFK Thanks for help.... I have edited code. First I wanted add delay for close...or have you better idea ?

Comment: I shouldn't be debugging your code but if you bind a `click` to an element like `$("#submitemail").click()`, at least an element with `id="submitemail"` should exist and I don't see any in your code (neither I see any `id="btnForm"`). BTW, the php code is not relevant within the context of your question. Please post only the rendered html.

Comment: Better now ? Thanks again !

Comment: what about `$("#submitemail").click()`?

Comment: You have right sry I'm totaly blind now is already fix code ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is in success function like:

```
setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 5000);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try triggering a click on the fancybox close button.

```
$('#fancybox-close').trigger('click');
```